# Windows recovery error on boot

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, bootrepair

I have recently been getting an error on my PC after the machine BSOD and then hung for an hour. I decided that the PC was frozen and hit the restart button on my PC. After the PC started to turn back on, I got this error:

Recovery

Your PC/Device need to be repaired

The operating system couldn't be loaded because a critical system driver is missing or contains errors.

File: \WINDOWS\System32\drivers\EPMVolFlt.sys
Error code: 0xc000007b

You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer.

Press Enter to try again
Press F8 for Startup Settings

Any advice? I really need my PC back.

Comment: You don't need more advice than the one written in the error message.

Comment: I used my recovery USB. I have no restore points, and I don't know how to fix the drivers.

Comment: https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/quick-fixes-for-windows-stuck-on-repairing-disk-error-in-windows-10-8-7.html

Comment: The errors they describe on your website do not look very similar to the errors I'm facing.

Comment: The point is not the errors but how to correct them from recovery. You need to run `chkdsk`, the error correction tool for partitions. Then, if are now able to boot normally, check the disk throughly for defects and replace it if it has bad sectors, etc.

Comment: Ok, I will try this in the morning.